# What's the difference between a USB 3.0 to SATA III adapter with an AC power supply and one without?

Tags: usb, ssd, sata, usb-3, usb-to-sata

I need an adapter for transferring files between my SSD and my laptop (Dell Latitude E7440). Will there be a difference in performance with a power cable? Will one without a power cable be reliable for an SSD? What about if I use it for an HDD?

Comment: A separate power cable will (usually) free up pins in the connector to complete the data transfer at a more favourable rate.

Comment: Most 3.5" HDD requires more power than an USB port can deliver - hence an AC adapter is needed. Smaller HDDs and SSDs usually don't need that much power and can be powered if connected to an USB 3.0+ port.

Comment: Power adapters are only required for HDDs that require 12v (3.5" drives) and you don't need one with a power adapter for an SSD.  You will want an all-metal adapter case if the SSD is not a 2.5" _(such as those made by Orico)_, as the SSD will get extremely hot during large file transfers.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between a USB 3.0 to SATA III adapter with an AC
>   power supply and one without?

The difference would be that the former device (with external power) will more likely to operate with almost any USB host system (and also handle HDD and SSD), while the latter will fail on many of them, especially on power-limited mobile devices like laptops.